# HTML: Is there any way to determine if an element is behind another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have an application with a search popup. You search for a term, and it finds them in the page and add a class to the word which in turn highlights the text.  Occasionally the found instance is in an area of the page that is behind the search popup. If that is the case, I'd like tone the opacity down of the search popup so the user can see the instance behind it.  Is there any simple way to do this? Any tips or tricks are appreciated. One requirement is that the search popup stay open after a search, so we can't just close/hide it.

Comment: could you perhaps provide some markup?

Comment: Are you using JQuery?  Can you scroll in the result content area? If scrollable, user just need to scroll around to see all the results. And more important: Is yopur searchbox position fixed or absolute ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` on the found text and the popup and compare the dimensions.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
**MDN** [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.getBoundingClientRect), [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect)

You can act on text ranges directly, but it sounds like you have an element wrapping the found text in order to apply the highlight, so I'd just use that element.  I think you can just pass your found text and your popup to this function to test if they overlap:

```
function isOverlapping (a, b)
{
    var rectA = a.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rectB = b.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rectA.top < rectB.bottom && rectA.bottom > rectB.top &&
        rectA.left < rectB.right && rectA.right > rectB.left;
}
```

**Edit:** I must have way too much time on my hands, because here's a fun little demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/qUFLJ/4/

Comment: Cool stuff man, I know it's bad but I'm itching to go look for a situation where I can implement this in a live application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using JavaScript it would be easy. Since you know if the popup is open, i assume that you know it's width and position. Just create a bounding box and check if your element is within this box. [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) is useful for this. If you're using jQuery, .[offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) can also help you.

Let me know if you need an example.